# problems with my /etc/profile

Tags: etc

I am a rookie in ubuntu, I tried to install java but I think it was installed yet (I didn't check it before, sorry), now an error pops up appears in my screen every time I log in

```
/etc/profile: line 28: $'E[200~': order not found
```

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: welcome to AskUbuntu.  In order to help experts answer your question, you need to be a lot more specific on what you are trying to do and ad the version of Ubuntu and any other software version you are trying to instal or use.

Answer (score 0):

Line 28 of your `/etc/profile` has that character string in it, and the shell couldn't understand it. Look at the line with

```
sed -n -e '28p' /etc/profile | \
  od -bc
```

and delete the funny characters with your favorite editor.